# (Lubuntu) How to move close, minimize and maximize to the left

Tags: lubuntu, window-buttons

There seem to be plenty of responses for GNOME Shell and Unity, but I'm not sure about Lubuntu. I just found very old answers on other sites (For releases <10.04 etc) but didn't want to try them in case things had changed and I broke something. So how do I move the three buttons (close, maximize and minimize) from their current position on the upper right hand corner of the window, to the upper left hand corner?
(Using an up to date Lubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the *"Preferences > Customize Look and Feel"* menu we choose the *"Window Border > Title Bar"* tab where settings of windows button order can be made.

[image]

Changes we made will immediately be displayed in a preview to the right side. If we were happy, press *Apply*.